# Make Unity resolve implementations considering contravariance

Tags: c#, polymorphism, unity-container, contravariance

I want to use unity for a polymorphic event aggregation/handling where handlers are registered through the container.

Handlers declares a generic parameter with the "in" modifier, since it's only used as an input parameter. So the parameter is contravariant.

Considering the following sample.

```cs
interface IHandler<in T> { void Handle(T message); }

interface IMsg { string Message { get; } }

class MsgA : IMsg { ... }

class MsgB : IMsg { ... }

class MsgAHandler : IHandler<MsgA> {
  public void Handle(MsgA msg) { ... }
}

class MsgBHandler : IHandler<MsgB> {
  public void Handle(MsgB msg) { ... }
}

class MsgHandler : IHandler<IMsg> {
  public void Handle(IMsg msg) { ... }
}

class ObjectHandler : IHandler<object> {
  public void Handle(object msg) { ... }
}

class Events {
   public void Publish<T>(T message) {
     // Actually this code is more complex for Unity, because it first tries to
     // resolve the default registered component using .Resolve(),
     // then use .ResolveAll() to resolve all named components
     foreach (var handler in this.container.ResolveAll<IHandle<T>>()) {
       handler.Handle(message);
     }
   }
}
```

My expectations are the followings :

- If I receive a `MsgA`, I should dispatch it to `MsgAHandler`, `MsgHandler` and `ObjectHandler`.
- If I receive a `IMsg`, I should dispatch it to `MsgHandler` and `ObjectHandler`.
- `ObjectHandler` should receive all messages.

By default, Castle Windsor handles correctly this scenario without any specific configuration (tested with v2.5.1).

Does Unity exposes a way to enhance the resolution and allow `Resolve<IHandle<MsgA>>()` to also match any type implementing `IHandle<IMsg>` or `IHandle<object>` ?

I've looked for samples using UnityExtensions (matching rules, policies, and so on) without success.

Could someone directs me to the correct mechanism to use to implement a such scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IHandle<>), typeof(MsgAHandler<>))
```

But you would probably need to change some of your code for that to work properly. Like:

```
public interface IHandler<in THandler> where THandler : class, IMsg
{ void Handle(THandler message); }
```